# How to mute VLCMediaPlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, vlc

I placed 2 VLCMediaPlayer in the IPad ViewController.
Then I want to mute one of the players.
I executed the following code from VLCAudio class:

```
[VLCMediaPlayer.audio setMute:YES];
```

But the voice of the player was still on.
Then I added another piece of code:

```
[VLCMediaPlayer.audio setVolume:0];
```

Nothing had been changed.

Is it because both setMute and setVolue functions don’t work under the ISO VLCKit?
If so, how to mute VLCMediaPlayer by coding?

Answer (score 2):

Set the current audio track to -1. Performance-wise, this is more efficient, too, since the audio information isn't even decoded.

Volume control (incl. mute) isn't supported with current versions of MobileVLCKit on iOS, but on the Mac only.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to mute from the beginning, I found a way to do it.
Before you send play msg to the player instance, you should init it with options, such as

```
self.player = [[VLCMediaPlayer alloc] initWithOptions:@[@"--gain=0"]];
```

where "--gain=0" which means audio gain set to 0. This is not the documentation method, may not work on every version of mobile vlc framework. But it works for me.

If you want to mute while playing, you can try

```
self.player.currentAudioTrackIndex = -1;
```

This also works for me!

Comment: After disabling the audio during the initial instantiation of the media player, is there a way to turn it back on? I tried setting currentAudioTrackIndex to a positive value but the audio stayed off. 
Thanks.

Comment: Same happens to me as well @CaseyPerkins. need some solutions please